# Do Ashari's believe the Qur'an is created?

Tags: aqidah

I have seen on some sites views from Asharis that show that some believe the Qur'an is created while others do not. Need clarity on this subject.

Ibn al-Jawzi says in al-Muntadham of al-Ash’ari: “The people never differed that this audible Qur’an is Allah’s Speech, and that Gabriel descended with it upon the Prophet – Allah’s peace and blessings be upon him. The reliable imams declared that the Quran is eternal, while the Mu’tazila claimed that it is created. Al-Ash’ari then agreed with the Mu’tazila that the Quran is created and said: ‘This is not Allah’s Speech. Rather, Allah’s Speech is an Attribute subsisting in Allah’s Essence. It did not descend on the Prophet, nor is it audible

Comment: Yes fine but this should be shared in your post. I read similar statements on Salafi sites. In fact except with Salafi's and Hanbali's not much people regard this topic as crucial as they do. It is a different of opinion and a difference in how to define a specific term "مُحْدَث". Years ago I read an article saying something like imam Ahmad suffered for something insignificant. The author certainly was not a scholar or student of Islamic knowledge, but a journalist.

Comment: @Medi1Saif this is a standard belief amongst Ahl al Sunnah, not just amongst Salafiyyah. Even Imam Malik (rh) stated that whoever stated the Quran is created is a kafir. Imam Ahmad (rh) was persecuted because of it and too deemed whoever said the Quran is created is a kafir.

Comment: All ahl as-Sunnah agree that Kalam Allah the word of Allah is not created. Now as far as I understood the texts I've consulted: as for whether the qur'an as performed (recited/read) by humans is Kalam Allah here's the difference of opinion. Some early sects said that the qur'an was created in/from al-Lawh al-Mahfudh. And therefore they accepted it being "مُحْدَث" they made a difference between several meanings of "creation". Imam Ahmad rejected this. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

- No: Quran which is God's word is created.
- Yes: Quran which you read in
  Mushafs or recite in your recitations is created. Even Imam Bukhari
  believed this.

Comment: Citation for Imam Al Bukhari's views needed.

Comment: Imam al-Bukhari was accused of saying that the Qur'an was makhluq but in reality he was saying the words only that we are reciting are makhluq. When the 'ulema heard about this everyone ceased to communicate to him.... However, Imam Muslim stopped taking any narrations from Imam al-Bukhari............. - Ibn Hajar Asqalani's Tahdhib al-Tahdhib (Please read the full incident with context yourself, I don't remember the page#)